# PHP preg_match_all no character or not a certain character

Tags: php, regex

Right now the test seems to be working for avoiding the characters that I don't want but it's only returning a count of 2.  I know why, I just don't know how to address it.  The problem is the last ? is being excluded because the actual match for the 2nd match is `(?+` so it's not matching the 3rd since there is no "starting" character for that pattern, it would just be `?)`.

```
$pattern =  "/([^\w\d'\"`]\?[^\w\d'\"`])/";
$subject = "`test` = ? and `other` = (?+?)";
$count = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo "Count: $count\n"; // echoes 2 instead of 3
```

Basically, I want to count up all the parameters used, so match all `?` in the `$subject` with a `?` not surrounded by letters, numbers, quotes, and ticks.

This is the actual pattern that matters:

```
[^\w\d'\"'`]
```

**Update:** 
For others, miken32's solution is to convert the above pattern to:

```
(?=[^\w\d'\"'`])
```

Comment: Are you trying to only match the `?`, because right now you're matching more than that.

Comment: @l'L'l yes, only the ?'s.  This is for analyzing a parameterized query.

Comment: Well you're also matching `\s`, `(`, `+` too... If you only want to match the `?` and nothing else I think you can just use `(?=[^\w\d'\"\`])\?`. The second one you have seems unnecessary.

Comment: @l'L'l, yes if they are touching a `?`, you mean?  All that matters to me for this is the count, but miken32's solution fixed that as well.

Comment: @l'L'l, that would still match something like `'What is the question ?'` in the prepared statement.

Comment: It looks like it does that now.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, [this](https://regex101.com/r/uK0iI9/3) seems the same as [this](https://regex101.com/r/uK0iI9/1).

Comment: You're missing the quotes.  `What is your question?` isn't valid SQL, `'What is your question?'` could be a string rather than a parameter for a prepared query.  This definitely still won't be a perfect solution but it's good enough for me for now.

Comment: He's correct that a question mark surrounded by white space will be counted, even if it is contained in a string. But fixing that seems like it's getting beyond what a regexp is meant for...

Comment: @Devon: Where was SQL even mentioned in your question?

Comment: @l'L'l, not really mentioned but implied by `count up parameters` and `this is for analyzing a parameterized query`.

Comment: You might add the `SQL` tag to your question... it wasn't obvious at all to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$pattern =  "/((?<=[^\w\d'\"`])\?(?=[^\w\d'\"`]))/";
```

It will look ahead without moving the search forward.

Edited to add the lookbehind assertion as well.

Comment: Looks like I should be doing that on both sides actually but this seems to be a perfect fit, thanks.  I will accept it soon unless someone one ups you :)

Comment: Why not just do `(?:[^\w\d'\"\`])\?`, or `(?=[^\w\d'\"\`])\?`